# list comprehension and exclusion in one value

Tags: python-3.x

I'm having an issue in python3. I want to exclude 0  as one of the values, however I can't seem to make that happen. I attempted adding another "and if" parameter but the result still included 0.

I want the values that are multiples of 6 between 1 and 100. 0 is clearly not one of them.

```
x for x in range(100) if x % 6 == 0
```

Answer (score 2):

The most direct answer is just

```
range(6, 101, 6)
```

But your original approach should work if you do something like:

```
[x for x in range(101) if x % 6 == 0 and x != 0]
```

(no `and if` needed, it's just a single `if` clause with a compound test).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
x for x in range(100) if x%6 == 0 and x != 0
```

or simply:

```
x for x in range(1,100) if x%6 == 0
```

Comment: I thought I had tried this exact same code, but this clearly works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exclude 0, don't include it in the first place :

```
range(1, 100)
```